# Find a date, format yyyy-mm-dd, by searching in a MongoDB, where each date is ISODate

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I got into this problem for a few days and I can't find any solution, even I searched on internet a lot.

I have a MongoDB database and each object has a property, lets say myDate, that is stored as ISODate.

When I search inside the project I use, inside the form input, date in **yyyy-mm-dd format**, lets say for ex **2003-04-28**.

Then when I look for this date, inside MongoDB I use $match to match that myDate property in each object from database:

```
const $match = {};

if(searchedDate) {
  $match['myDate'] = searchedDate
}
```

but in database, each object has this property, this date, stored in this way

```
{
  "myDate": ISODate("2023-04-28T00:00:00.000+0000)
}
```

The code works without any error but in final I get inside response body: No Content.

In other colletion, same project, the date was the ID(the ID being **yyyy-mm-dd format**, lets say for ex **2003-04-28**) of each object and that was easy, for what date I was searching I was getting exactly that object with that date ID, but here I can't find the solution.

Can someone please give me a little help or some ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Are you using Node.js with MongoDB driver?

Comment: Yes, NodeJS and MongoDB driver. So I don't use mongoose.

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/YOkdvo9WDNv another possible option using agregate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try using the `$eq` operator here like this:

```js
if (searchedDate) {
  // Make your "yyyy-mm-dd" Date string to ISODate
  const isoDate = new Date(searchedDate);

  const query = {
    myDate: { $eq: isoDate }
  };

  return await collection.find(query).toArray();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Works in your way and also in my way too, modified, inspired by you: ```$match['myDate'] = new Date(searchedDate)``` :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help ;)